# Extract the Day of the month (dd) from a date in Query()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a list of transactions for a month, all include a date (Column B - dd/mm/yyyy) and a £in figure (Column F). I want to create a table that shows the total taken on each day of the month so for example on the April sheet, calculate the sum of all sales on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd

> =SUM(QUERY($A$3:$F, "select F where 'TEXT(B,dd)' = 1",0))
>
> =SUM(QUERY($A$3:$F, "select F where 'TEXT(B,dd)' = 2",0))
>
> =SUM(QUERY($A$3:$F, "select F where 'TEXT(B,dd)' = 3",0))

This completes the query successfully but returns no results, despite there being transactions on these days.

Thanks

It would also be ideal if there was a way to input the formula so it can be filled into each row upto 31, without changing the date on each row

sample sheet with relevant data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nkwh1F3_3_bFdakkijjjRcKMUHJUOJ22QJKOWjzycnM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Please share the link to a test sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nkwh1F3_3_bFdakkijjjRcKMUHJUOJ22QJKOWjzycnM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the day of the month  by using `QUERY`, use `day()`

Example:

```
=QUERY($A3:$F,"select F where day(B) = 1")
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a query formula:

```
=query(A1:B, "select A, sum(B) where A is not null group by A order by A asc label sum(B) 'Takings'",1)
```

You can then format your cells to show just the day of the date or whatever you like by going to:
`Format` >> `Number` >> `More formats` >> `More date and time formats`

Functions used:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Thanks, This is very close to what I need, but I want to see the sum for every day, even if there are no transactions

Comment: _"It would also be ideal if there was a way to input the formula so it can be filled into each row up to 31, without changing the date on each row"_. Have you solved your issue. Was `day(B) = 1` enough?